# Total Payment & recurring Payment option for a product

Tags: product, payment, recurring

If I have created recurring profile for one product then is it compulsory for me to pay in installments or I can pay total amount also.

Selection between total amount pay or pay in installments is possible or not?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to set up two separate products, one that is billed monthly and one that is billed annually or one-off. You can then link the customer to the appropriate product depending on how they wish to pay.

Ideally, you'd want to create a configurable product which allows the customer to select Monthly vs Annual payments from a dropdown box, however Magento does not work well with configurable products and recurring profiles. You can use a module that allows you to set up a configurable product with recurring profiles such as [Stripe Subscriptions](http://store.cryozonic.com/magento-extensions/stripe-subscriptions.html), which can achieve the above, but only works with the Stripe payment gateway. See [this demo page](http://demo.cryozonic.com/subscriptions/coffee-beans.html) on how that would look like.

Disclaimer: I am the developer of the above module.

Answer (score 0):

If you have created a recurring profile for a product, you can choose to pay the total amount or pay in installments depending on the payment options such as [Stripe Payment Gateway](https://marketplace.magento.com/magenest-module-stripe-global.html). The recurring profile simply sets up a schedule for payments to be made automatically at regular interval. However, the payment options available to you may depend on the payment gateway or payment processor you are using. It is important to check with your payment provider to understand what payment options are available to you and how to set them up correctly.